# Changing custom view with button that is within the views themselves

Tags: xcode, macos

I have so far managed to create an `imageView` with a picture in order to create a background. (This takes up the whole window) I now want to switch to several views using buttons that are on top of this image! So far I have found many tutorials that show how to create a custom view and have buttons bellow in the `NSWindow`, but am unable to get my head around how to do it if the button is actually within the custom view.

The aim is to have the start up view which has a button saying "`start game`" clicking it will swap to a new view which again will have numerous buttons which will again switch to various other views.

I am new to Xcode and to this forum so if it has already been described somewhere please don't have a go, just point me in the direction. I have searched far and wide so it is not down to lack of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Set tag on button click..so that images can identified.

-(IBAction)editImage:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton*)sender;

if (tag==1) {
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [theButton setTag:2];
    }
    else if (tag==2){

```
    [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theButton setTag:1];
}
```

}
Hope this will help you